# How to write quotes (" or ') and quoted strings to a Razor view

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a bunch of constants to be used in JS saved in a RESX file, such as:

```
DATE_PICKER_FORMAT   yyyy-mm-dd  
DATETIME_FORMAT      yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss  
MONTH_PICKER_FORMAT  yyyy-mm
```

I wrote a simple class to help write this into JS on a Razor view:

```
public static class JavascriptResourceRenderer
{
    private static string Render(ResourceSet resources)
    {
        string resourceString = "";

        foreach (DictionaryEntry resource in resources)
        {
            resourceString += String.Format("var {0} = '{1}'; ", resource.Key, resource.Value);
        }

        return resourceString;
    }

    public static string RenderPageConstants()
    {
        ResourceSet resources = PageConstants.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
        return Render(resources);
    }
}
```

And in my view, I'm doing this:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        @JavascriptResourceRenderer.RenderPageConstants()
    </script>
}
```

The constants do get rendered when the view loads, except the quotes come out encoded.

Viewing the HTML using DOM inspector, this is what I see:

```
<script>
    var MONTH_PICKER_FORMAT = &#39;yyyy-mm&#39;;  
</script>
```

I've tried

```
"var {0} = '{1}'; "   // writes &#39;yyyy-mm&#39; to view
"var {0} = \"{1}\"; " // writes &quot;yyyy-mm&quot; to view
@"var {0} = "{1}"; "  // syntax error in String.Format
```

How can I write

```
<script>
    var MONTH_PICKER_FORMAT = "yyyy-mm"; // or 'yyyy-mm' (I want the quotes!)
</script>
```

to the view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should return your output as an [`MvcHtmlString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring(v=vs.118).aspx) instead, otherwise MVC will encode it:

```
private static MvcHtmlString Render(ResourceSet resources)
{
    string resourceString = "";

    foreach (DictionaryEntry resource in resources)
    {
        resourceString += String.Format("var {0} = '{1}'; ", resource.Key, resource.Value);
    }

    return new MvcHtmlString(resourceString);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the Html Helper method [`Html.Raw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx) in your view, but you need to remember to do that *every* time you call the method (which is why I would not recommend to do it this way):

```
@Html.Raw(JavascriptResourceRenderer.RenderPageConstants())
```

Answer (score 5):

Your string is getting HTML encoded.

You'll need to output raw text.  Your view needs to do this:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        @Html.Raw(JavascriptResourceRenderer.RenderPageConstants())
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Thanks! DavidG has the more complete answer, but good to know about Html.Raw!